# twitter rate limit question for web applications?

Tags: twitter

Looking at twitters documentation, I am not 100% of the following question I have.

If I have a web based application, which simply allows a user to login via their twitter details and post a message to 1 of their friends, will this application be rate limited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, posting a new status to Twitter using the [statuses/update](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) API method is not subject to rate-limiting.

Comment: Don't they have to be logged in before they can update a status?  Does that logging in action use rate limiting?

Comment: Yes, they have to be logged in, but the actual act of logging in is not rate limited.